# Unsupervised Supervised Clusters with NAs and Qualitative Data in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, unsupervised-learning

I have basketball player data that looks like the following:

```
 Player   Weight  Height  Shots   School 
  A         NA      70      23      AB
  B        130      62      10      AB
  C        180      66      NA      BC
  D        157      65      22      CD
```

and I want to do unsupervised and supervised(based on height) clustering. Looking into online resources I found that I can use kmeans for unsupervised but I don't know how to handle NAs without losing a good amount of data. I also don't know how to handle the quantitative variable "school". Are there any ways to resolve both issues for unsupervised and supervised clustering?

Answer (score 0):

K-means cannot be used for categorical data. One work around would be to instead use data about the schools such as # of enrollments or local SES data.

`kmeans()` in R cannot handle NA's so you could either omit them (and you should check that the NA's are distributed fairly evenly among other factors) or look into using `cluster::clara()` from the `cluster` library.

You have not asked anything specifically about super-learning so I cannot address that part of the question.

Comment: Thank you for your response @bmrn I was trying to approach this myself but seeing as I don't have enough knowledge of what I don't know, let me ask you the question that was asked of me. I would like to perform 2 tasks. One unsupervised clustering and one supervised clustering(weight) clustering of the players to look for insights on the data set above. How would you approach this? And if you cannot give an in depth analysis, are there any R packages you would recommend?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is known as missing data. And you have to decide about it before start the clustering. in most cases the samples with missed data (NAs here) are simple omitted. that happen in preparing data and clearing process step of data mining. In R you can do it using the following code:

```
na.omit(yourdata)
```

it omit the records or samples (in row) that contains NAs.

but if you want to include them in the clustering process you can use the average value of that feature in entire cluster for the missing value option. 
in your case, Consider weight:

> for player A you can set (130+180+157)/3 for his weight.

For another question: it seems you are a little bit confused about the meaning of supervised and unsupervised learning. in supervised learning you need to define the class label of the samples. then you build a model (classifier) and train it to learn about each class of samples and after training you can use the model to predict the label of a test sample, like you give it a player with this values (W=100,H=190,shots=55) and it will give you the predicted class label.

For unsupervised learning you just need to cluster the data to find group or cluster relation of samples. for doing this you do not need a class label, you should define the features that you are going to cluster the samples based on them, for example you can cluster players only based on their weights, or just cluster them based on their height,... or you can use all height, weight and shots features for clustering. this is possible in R using the following code:

```
clus <- kmeans(na.omit(data$weight), 5) #for cluster them to 5 clusters based on weight
clus <- kmeans(na.omit(data[,1:3]),5) # to cluster them based on weight, height, shots into 5 clusters.
```

consider the using of na.omit here that remove rows which has NAs in their columns.

let me know if this helps you.